# Count occurrences of specific dict value in list of dicts and create a new dict with that count

Tags: python, json

I have a list of dictionaries and what I want to do is to look for an specific value in all the dictionaries that my list have. Then I want to create a new dictionary with that value.

Input:

````
{ "Element": ["Box"]
  "Element2": ["Pen"]
}

{ "Element": ["Box"]
  "Element2": ["Pencil"]
}

]

Expected Output:

[
{ There are two box 
 There is one pen 
There is one pencil 
}
{ "Element": ["Box"]
  "Element2": ["Pen"]
}

{ "Element": ["Box"]
  "Element2": ["Pencil"]
}

] ```

How would you do that? Thanks in advance
````

Answer (score 0):

To simplify the code, the values of the dictionaries are strings instead of list here, but maybe some snippet helps you.

```
from functools import reduce

dictlist=[{ "Element": "Box", "Element2": "Pen"},{ "Element": "Box","Element2": "Pencil"}]

vals=reduce(lambda x,y:x+y,[list(dic.values()) for dic in dictlist])
for val in set(vals):
    print(f"There is {vals.count(val)} {val}")
```

Outputs:

```
There is 1 Pen
There is 1 Pencil
There is 2 Box
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get a list of all the values using `dict.values()`, and the use `.count(text)` to count the amount of occurrences of one type of element. Counting multiple ones might be what you want though.

Let's use your example.

```
elements = [
{ "Element": ["Box"], "Element2": ["Pen"]},
{ "Element": ["Box"], "Element2": ["Pencil"]}]

total = []
for i in elements:
    for j in i.values():
        total.extend(j)

counts = {}
for i in total:
    if i in counts.keys():
        counts[i]+=1
    else:
        counts[i] = 1

print(counts)
```

EDIT: After seeing Luka's request about an element3 NOT being added to the count, here is the adjusted code, with a list of blocked elements.

```
elements = [
{ "Element": ["Box"], "Element2": ["Pen"], "Element3": ["Scissor"]},
{ "Element": ["Box"], "Element2": ["Pencil"], "Element3": ["Highlighter"]}]

blocked = ["Element3"]
total = []
for i in elements:
    for key, value in i.items():
        if key not in blocked:
            total.extend(value)

counts = {}
for i in total:
    if i in counts.keys():
        counts[i]+=1
    else:
        counts[i] = 1

print(counts)
```

Comment: That's great but imagine I've a "Element3" that I don't want to add at the list

Comment: @Luka I've fixed it to add your scenario in.